# Is it possible to use a rig controller to control textures?

Tags: rigging

I have an eye, and I want to be able to change the size and shape of the pupil (seperate texture) and I’ve used shape keys, but they don’t work right, so I wondered if it would be possible to use a controller (like an empty) to control the faces of the sphere that the texture’s on without using shape keys. Thanks

Comment: I also want to use the same method to make eyes, the problem is that I continue and copy the examples and it doesn't work as it should, the image is only repeated and distorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can use an object as source of coordinate system:

[image]

[image]

Another way is using drivers:

[image]

Click RMB on empty's scale slider and select "copy as new driver"

Then paste it into shader node value. Now empty controls the value inside node tree:

[image]